# Setting y=0 to variable python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to change the y axis so that a given variable is set to y=0.

For example, say I'm looking at heights and I want 14 km to be the y=0 value, how would I do that in matplotlib?

Comment: Subtract 14 km from all of the y-values?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.yticks`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.yticks),

```
plt.yticks(y, label)
```